# Find shortest path with relationships condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a graph of bus stops interconnected by bus lines. Two stations can be connected by multiple lines. When searching for paths, I need to get paths with a minimum number of lines.

The relationships are coded like this:

```
(a)-[:CONNECTED_TO {line:lineid}]->(b)
```

I need to get the shortest paths between two nodes ordered by the number of different lineids. For example:

```
path 1 : (a)-[lineid1]->(b)-[lineid1]->(b)
path 2 : (a)-[lineid1]->(b)-[lineid2]->(b)
```

The first path must be ordered first because all of the stops are connected by the same line.
To choose between two paths,I have to pick the one with the minimum different lines but also with the minimum line transfer, for example:

```
path1 : 1-2-2-1-2-3
path2 : 1-1-2-2-3-3
```

I have to pick the path2

Comment: Did you intend paths 1 and 2 to go from `a` to `b` and then *back to* `b` again? It is unlikely that there are lines that immediately go from a stop back to the same stop. And in any case, neither of those paths would ever be the shortest path from `a` to `b`.

Comment: No, paths 1 and 2 will continue after these two stops each in different direction. They share (a) and (b) but continue with independant paths like this : 
1: x-a-b-c  and 2:e-a-b-d

Comment: OK, so can you fix the example in your question?

Comment: Also, do you really want paths with "a minimum number of lines"? Or, do you want paths with "the fewest line changes"? For example, suppose path 1 uses the lines 1-2-3-1-2-3, and path 2 uses the lines 1-1-2-2-3-3. You'd probably want to pick path 2 because it only requires a passenger to make 2 line changes during the trip (instead of 5), correct?

Comment: Correct the minimum line transfer is also a choice factor

Comment: I remember using the shortest path algorithms in Neo4j. if you are using cypher this link might help you https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/ you can also look in the SDK that they have provided.

Comment: @Vishrant, I am already using the shortestpath algo but this is not enough for  the required query, I need more details for the constraints I explained